# MongoDB How to replace array item by index

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

How would I replace a value at a specific index in an array using **MongoDB**?

Lets say a collection for movie reviews has a rating array with individual numbers and I wanted to replace one with a new rating using only **Indexes**

let array = [1, 5, 3, 7]

How do I replace 5 with 4? Once again only using **Indexes**

Comment: var i = array.indexOf(5);
array[i] = 4;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose, you have a document

```
{ 
    "_id" : 1, 
    "array" :  [1, 5, 3, 7]
}
```

then, you can update array value at specific index using **dot operator** 
i.e, `array.<index>` 
with [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/index.html) operator

```
db.collection.update(
  { /*match query*/ },
  { $set: { "array.1": 4 } }  // array.index where index=0,1,2,...
)
```

The Updated Document becomes,

```
{ 
    "_id" : 1, 
    "array" :  [1, 4, 3, 7]
}
```

You need to concatenate the index in key. Try this

```
 { _id: editedObj.id }, // Match id. 
{ $set: { [`reviews.${index}`]: editedObj.reviews}})
```

Comment: `{ _id: editedObj.id }, // Match id.
 { $set: { "reviews.index": editedObj.reviews}});` I am using node.js, when i try doing that using a variable with my index value it gives me an error. Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Goggies I have updated my code, Try this and let me know if this works for you or not.

Comment: Got this error `Cannot create field '${index}' in element {reviews: [ "test" ]}`

Comment: Will you Please Show me your Code.

Comment: `let updated = await Movie.updateOne(
                    { _id: editedObj.id }, // Match id.
                    { $set: { "reviews.${index}": editedObj.reviews}});`

Comment: im not sure how to post more but this is where I am trying to handle the update

Comment: Ok, let updated = await Movie.updateOne( { _id: editedObj.id }, // Match id. { $set: { [`reviews.${index}`]: editedObj.reviews}});

Comment: Actually you need to use Back-tick (`), instead of Double Quotes (") and put Object key inside []

Comment: Have you use Backtick, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Okay so i changed it to back-ticks and it seems to work althoug it is creating a sub-array in my array. Here is screenshot https://gyazo.com/5b7545c3a479c89745190aeacf2ffce0

Comment: Fixed it!! instead of just doing editedObj.reviews i did editedObj.reviews[0] as i am passing in an array with only one value (the new value) I really appreciate you helping me